# Using Only the First Letter in a String Stored in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently writing a "Pseudo Assembly Compiler" for the MC68HC11, it's nothing complex. The issue I'm having is after reading from a file and storing into an array.

For example, I have the line "LDAA #$45", I'm first saving "LDAA" into a string array and "#$45" into a second string array. I use the first array as is, but for the second one I only need to know what the first letter or symbol in that array is so I can know what if statement I need to end up in.

The code for going into LDAA would be something like this:

```
if(code[i]=="LDAA"){ //code is my array for the first word read.
  if(number[i]=="#"){ //Here's where I would only need to read the first symbol stored in the array.
    opcode[i]="86";
  }
}
```

The code I'm using for reading from a file is similar to that found in [Reading a file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664845/reading-a-file-into-an-array)?

I'm not sure if this is exactly possible as I can't find anything like it online.

Comment: See this article @ CodeProject...

It might give you some better ideas then you currently have...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578116/Complete-Managed-Media-Aggregation-Part-III-Quantu

Comment: please provide some code to illustrate the issue, for us to more easily understand it.

Comment: @didierc Added some code.

Comment: is the problem to access the first char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged this C++, so I'm going to assume your array contains `std::string`s, in which case:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "#$45";
    std::string firstLetter = foo.substr(0, 1);
    std::cout << firstLetter;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces output:

> #

Is that what you were looking for? Applying to your code:

```
if(code[i]=="LDAA"){
  if(number[i].substr(0, 1)=="#"){
    opcode[i]="86";
  }
}
```

Comment: It is indeed std::string and yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of `number`, you want either:

```
if(number[i]=='#'){
```

or

```
if( number[i][0]=='#'){
```

Also, are `code[i]`, `opcode[i]` of type `std::string` or `char*`. [ Hopefully the former.]

Comment: They're of type std::string.